# Is there a way to check next level stats of a gem before leveling it?

Tags: path-of-exile

Can I check what stats will a skill gem have on its next level before I click on the upgrade (level up) button? I couldn't find an option for that and really don't feel like going to PoE wiki everytime I want to see gem stats for its next level.

Comment: Nope.  All you can see is the requirements for the new level.  That's it.

Comment: fbueckert is correct, and GGG stated that they are aware of the issue and it is on the future feature list. Currently you have to resort to wikis to find the stats for the next level.

Comment: In the meantime, there's an ongoing list on the wiki with the stats of all gems. Just click the one you want to check out: en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Gem#Gems

Comment: @Anto If you would have read my question you would see i said I'm using PoE wiki to check on stats of gems already...

Comment: Yeah but I didn't.  :D

Comment: You can check the requirements of skills on the [Wiki](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Gems#Gems)

Comment: @Cresh Read the question all the way before answering or commenting. I already stated in my question that I'm currently going to PoE wiki for that. Anto replied with same comment like you as well, so i see you didn't read his comment either...

Comment: My apologies, I actually added the comment with the direct link to the skill gem section of the wiki as a convenience for future reading. It can't have been too far off since it was approved in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there is currently no easy way of seeing the next level's stats for a gem besides the [wiki](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Gems#Gems). However, if you have an item with the gem level+1 mod, you can put the gem in it to see what it does at the next level.

Comment: @Cresh Thanks for the edit man, I should have included that.